# Download Excel files from website where filename changes

Tags: html, excel, vba, web-scraping

I am trying to download files from the PPAC website.  The code works, however the filename changes each month and isn't always logical (i.e. the filename contains a ddmmyyyy, but that date may be any day in the month).

How can I download the file with a general name?

One route I'm hoping will be useful is the HTML tags - the filename is shown within the following

```
<H5>Installed Refinery Capacity</H5>
<ul>
<li>
<a href HERE LIES MY TARGET FILE ... </a>
```

So then, the bullet point below heading "Installed Refinery Capacity" contains my file name, which will be consistent except for the date.
Another option is to loop through a number of dates until I hit upon the correct one.

```
Sub DownloadFile()

Dim myURL As String

'myURL = "https://www.ppac.gov.in/WriteReadData/userfiles/file/PT_installed_24-04-2020.xls?your_query_parameters"
myURL = "https://www.ppac.gov.in/WriteReadData/userfiles/file/PT_installed_24-04-2020.xls"
'myURL = Cells(10, 3)

Dim WinHttpReq As Object
Set WinHttpReq = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
WinHttpReq.Open "GET", myURL, False, "username", "password"
WinHttpReq.send

If WinHttpReq.Status = 200 Then
    Set oStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
    oStream.Open
    oStream.Type = 1
    oStream.Write WinHttpReq.responseBody
    oStream.SaveToFile "C:\tmp\file.csv", 2 ' 1 = no overwrite, 2 = overwrite
    oStream.Close
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: For today's file you can use  `myURL = "https://www.ppac.gov.in/WriteReadData/userfiles/file/PT_installed_" & Format(Date, "dd-mm-yyyy") & ".xls"`.

Comment: Thank you for your response. . yes.  but im lazy and i won't run the macro each day, so the date might be todays date but it might be a different date.

Comment: In addition to @VBasic2008 's suggestion .. It seems you are looking for multiple files download. You can use input boxes for Start Date and End Date and then put the download code in a loop for dates in the given period..

Comment: I've visited `https://www.ppac.gov.in/content/146_1_ProductionPetroleum.aspx` and looked at the last link. It points to `24-04-2020.xls`. So you should find a way how to check if a file with a date exists (to maybe retrieve the older or (not likely) the newer files),

Answer (score 0):

Make an initial XmlHttp request to

```
https://www.ppac.gov.in/content/146_1_ProductionPetroleum.aspx
```

Read the `.responseText` into `html.body.innerHTML` of an instantiated `MSHTML.HTMLDocument` variable.

Substring match with a css [attribute = value selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) (and contains operator *) to get the right href:

```
Dim link As String

link = html.querySelector("[href*='PT_installed']").href
```

Continue with your code using that link.

---

Or as helper function, something like:

```
Public Sub DownloadFile()

    Dim myURL As String

    myURL = "https://www.ppac.gov.in" & GetLink("https://www.ppac.gov.in/content/146_1_ProductionPetroleum.aspx")

    Dim WinHttpReq As Object
    Set WinHttpReq = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
    WinHttpReq.Open "GET", myURL, False, "username", "password"
    WinHttpReq.send

    If WinHttpReq.Status = 200 Then
        Set oStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
        oStream.Open
        oStream.Type = 1
        oStream.Write WinHttpReq.responseBody
        oStream.SaveToFile "C:\tmp\file.csv", 2 ' 1 = no overwrite, 2 = overwrite
        oStream.Close
    End If

End Sub

Public Function GetLink(ByVal url As String) As String
    Dim xhr As Object html As MSHTML.HTMLDocument 'required VBE > Tools > References > Microsoft HTML Object Library
    Set xhr = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    Set html = New MSHTML.HTMLDocument

    With xhr
        .Open "GET", url , False
        .send
        html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
    End With

    GetLink = html.querySelector("[href*='PT_installed']").href
End Function
```

Comment: That sounds excellent, im not clever enough to implement but i will have a go.  thanks.

Comment: thank you, this is very helpful.   There are some typos in the function, eg, end sub rather than end function.. but perhpas I don't know what I'm talking about.  Also, the html.querySelector returns Getlink = about:/WriteReadData/userfiles/file/PT_installed_24-04-2020.xls  rather than the path.. but I will try to sort it out from here.. thank you for your code... I wish I could do that :)

Comment: Oops... as I can't test code and am writing code outside of vba compiler I missed that. I have updated to correct. Try running the above and let me know.